# What batteries for the Inspiron N5040 laptop would last longer than 3 hours, and how much longer?

Tags: laptop, dell-inspiron

A friend of mine recently purchased a Inspiron N5040 laptop and is not satisfied with the battery life. She is looking for batteries for the computer that would last longer than the 3-hour per charge batteries that the computer comes with. A Google search yields a list of batteries for the computer (6 cell and 9 cell) but does not say how long they last per charge. Where could I find a listing of batteries for this computer and their expected life per charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All batteries for this laptop are 11.1V, so the current capacity will determine the run time. The available battery ratings and approximate run times are as follows:

Six cell, older design, 4300mAH rating: 3 hours.

Six cell, newer design, 5200mAH rating: 3 and a half hours.

Nine cell, older design, 7800mAH rating: 5 hours, 20 minutes.

Nine cell, newer design, 8100mAH rating: 5 hours, 40 minutes.